# mongos Socket operation timed out

Tags: mongodb, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53

I've got a mongos router running on amazon ECS in an EC2 machine, and also hosted on a route53 hosted zone.
The thing is that I can reach the mongos service via HTTP with the record name:
https://mongos-router.awsqa.xxx.net/
With the response:

> It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native
> driver port.

Which means that mongos is running correctly.

The ecs logs I get shows its running correctly also.

But trying to connect to it via mongo command:

```
$ mongo --host mongos-router.awsqa.xxx.net
MongoDB shell version v4.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://mongos-router.awsqa.xxx.net:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server mongos-router.awsqa.xxx.net:27017, connection attempt failed: NetworkTimeout: Error connecting to mongos-router.awsqa.xxx.net:27017 (xx.xxx.xx.xx:27017) :: caused by :: Socket operation timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I've confirmed that the container port is correct also:

```
"portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 0,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 27017
        }
      ],
```

a part of mongos.conf file:

```
net:
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  port: 27017
```

Dockerfile final command:

```
CMD [ "mongos", "--config", "/etc/mongos.conf" ]
```

Any idea at all to what is causing this network timeout error will be helpful

Comment: @Joe yes, I run the mongo command specifying --tls, --tlsCAFile and --tlsCertificateKeyFile. Didn't include this because that's not where the problem is coming from